# Calling a Blazor Component from a C# Class

Tags: electron, components, blazor

I need help on an implementation of a problem I have encountered. I'm currently coding a Blazor application. My index.razor component has the following code.

```
@page "/"
@namespace AutoHarp3_Server.Pages
@using ElectronNET.API;
@using ElectronNET.API.Entities;
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject pCharStat pCharStat

<div class="FullColorBackground vh-100">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <div class="p-4 bg-light-opactity-light border rounded-lg">
            <div class="w-100">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-gradient shadow w-100" @onclick="() => CreateNewCharacter()">Create New Character</button>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 w-100">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-gradient shadow w-100" @onclick="() => OpenCharacter()">Open Character</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        pCharStat.electron = new ElectronCls(new pCharacterCls());
        pCharStat.electron.BuildMenu();
    }

    async Task CreateNewCharacter()
    {
        //User Clicks on button from component I am brought here to make construct a new character. 
    }
    async Task SaveCharacter()
    {
       //User clicks on button from component I am brought here to save the character to a file 
    }

    async Task OpenCharacter()
    {
        //User click on button from component I am brought here to open a character file. 
    }
}
```

All of this works great from the component. But in Electron there is also the menu options for each of these "NewCharacter", "SaveCharacter", and "OpenCharacter". We can see this from the ElectronCls.cs object shown below.

```
using AutoHarp3_Server.Data.Classes.CharacterClasses;
using AutoHarp3_Server.Pages;
using ElectronNET.API;
using ElectronNET.API.Entities;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace AutoHarp3_Server.Data.Classes
{
    public class ElectronCls
    {
        public ElectronCls()
        {
        }

        public string FilePath { get; set; } = "";

        public void BuildMenu()
        { 
            //Code to build menu
        }

        public async Task NewCharacter()
        {
            //Electron Menu will call this function here! How do I gain access to my index.razor component so I can move functionality to that component. I want to do this because my main character object is located there. 
        }

        public async Task ShowOpenDialog(bool CharacterFile = true, bool ImageFile = false)
        {
            //electron Menu will call this function here! How do I gain access to my index.razor component so I can move functionality to that component. I want to do this because my main character object is located there.               
        }
        public async Task ShowSaveDialog()
        {
            //electron Menu will call this function here! How do I gain access to my index.razor component so I can move functionality to that component. I want to do this because my main character object is located there. 
        }
    }
}
```

If the user uses the electron menu I do not see any way from going to the methods I have defined in my ElectronCls.cs object to the index.razor component. I do not see any way to call it. I'm not sure this is possible or if this is the way one should do it in Blazor. The reason I need to find a solution is that since this is an Electron application, the user could use the menu. I should have that option open to them. If there is no way to accomplish this, I suppose I can look into removing the menu altogether from the application.

EDIT: for clarification purposes as requested.

Comment: Can you simplify your code to include just the important parts?

Comment: Tried to simplify but not sure if I have removed too much. Added more comments to hopefully clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: So you are looking for a way of communication from ElectronCls.ShowSaveDialog to Index.razor?

Comment: Yeah... I think I found a way by making a child component to index.razor and adding a @ref to that component and then passing that component to my ElectronCls. It seemed to work but I keep running into other electron errors that is preventing me from truly testing this.